# Is there any way I could change parameters of render using redirect in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to change render parameters in Django but, by calling a redirect method.

```
def abc(request):
    theatre =  Theatre.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'book_tickets/post_list.html', {'theatre':theatre, 'flag': False})
```

And I have another xyz function, where I want to do something like this:

```
def xyz(request):
    if (something):
        return redirect('post_list', 'flag':True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use kwargs to send the variable

```
def abc(request, **kwargs):
    try:
       flag = kwargs['flag']
    except:
       flag = False
    theatre =  Theatre.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'book_tickets/post_list.html', {'theatre':theatre, 'flag': flag})
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what changes should I make in my xyz function?

Comment: I cannot remember exactly.  It is something like `return redirect('post_list', { 'flag':True })`